# Magento2: How to set a "deal of the day" for a configurable product

Tags: magento2

I can set the **deal of the day** for a **simple product** and everything works fine.

1)[image]

[image]

2) but how to set **deal of the day** for **configurable product**?
- in main configurable product impossible to edit price:
[image]

When I try edit price in each size for this configurable product then no work.